# GNU parallel: different commands to different computers?

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Have searched on SO and GNU parallel tutorial and gone through examples [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__distributing_work_to_local_and_remote_computers), but still don't quite see what I need solved. Any tips appreciated on how I could accomplish the following:

I need to invoke the same script on several remote servers with a different argument passed to each one (argument is a string), then wait until all those jobs are done... Then, run that same script some more times on those same remote servers, but this time try to keep the remote servers as busy as possible (ie when they finish their job, send them another job). Ideally the strings could be read in from a file on the "master" machine that is sending the jobs to the remote servers.

To diagram this, I'm trying to run *my_script* like this:

- server A:  *myscript fee*
- server B:  *myscript fi*

When both jobs are done I then want to do something like:

- server A: *myscript fo*
- server B: *myscript fum*

... and supposing A finished its work before server B, immediately sending it the next job like :

- server A: *myscript englishmun*

... etc

Again, hugely appreciate any ideas people might have about whether this is easy/hard with GNU parallel (or if something else like pdsh, cluster ssh, might be better suited).

TIA!

Answer (score 2):

It seems we can split the problem up in two parts: An initialization part that needs to be run on all server and a job processing part that does not care which server it is run on.

The last part is GNU Parallel's specialty:

```
cat argfile | parallel -S serverA,serverB myscript
```

The first part is a bit more tricky: You want the first k arguments to go onto to k servers.

```
head -n 2 argfile | parallel -j1 -S serverA,serverB myscript
```

The problem is here that if there are loads of servers, then serverA may finish before you get to the last server. It is much easier to run the same job on all servers:

```
head -n 1 argfile | parallel --onall -S serverA,serverB myscript
```

Comment: THank you, this is very helpful. So, does Gnu parallel wait for all the servers to finish during the first phase, before going on to the second phase? ie, if I do head -n 2 argfile | parallel -j1 -S serverA,serverB myscript, then cat argfile | parallel -S serverA,serverB myscript, will it not start to run the second parallel command before the first set of jobs is done? This is key because the first set HAVE to be done before the second set can run.

Comment: Yes. In that respect GNU Parallel is very similar to most other UNIX commands: It returns when it is done.